# Protractor - send keys to desktop application BankID

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I wonder if anyone can help me with this little problem I am facing right now.

I use Protractor to build automated tests for our trading site here in sweden.
And our customers can use BankID to authenticate and login to the trading site.

When you click the button "Login with BankID" an installed application opens up where you can enter your password and click "Authenticate"

[See the BankID login here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hclw2.png)

And here comes my questions:

1. How can I send my keys to the password-field in the application?
2. How can I perform a click on the "Auth" button?

I really need help with this. 
Thank you!

Comment: can you show how some of the html for the signin popup. I'm assuming it's provided by a third-party, is it written in angular?

Comment: Hi, signin is not a webpage. It's an installed application on my computer that opens up. And it closes after entering password and clicking auth-button.

So I need to send my password keys to this application that opens and hit ENTER.

Comment: I see. It appears though that your application is being hidden in the background when this prompt is open, correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Yes thats correct! When this prompt is open you can only access the BankId application

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the keyboard action. Since `protractor` will support only web automation.

Note: This can be used only if the your cursor focus will go to the installed application text box. If not the answer will not help you

So to type the `password` use `browser.actions().sendKeys('//Your password').perform();`

Now to navigate across the application use `TAB` as `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();`

After Moving to `auth` button use ENTER as `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();`

Add some `sleep` after every action. I am not sure but lets give a try.

Hope it helps you.